# word-wrap:break-word alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't make it work on FF and Chrome while it plays well on IE/Opera. I there a way to do it, even with Javascript/JQuery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more control over where, you can use [an HTML element](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html).

Answer (score 3):

That's a CSS attribute.

I found this solution posted elsewhere, but haven't tried it.

```
.wrapword{ 
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */ 
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */ 
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */ 
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */ 
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */ 
}
```

If FF has trouble breaking a word when doing wrapping, a sure way to force it is to have a function that breaks up words over a certain length, inserting a character that ffox will break on.  You can do a browser check to only do that on browsers that need it.